# Sass compiling and transforming special characters

Tags: css, sass

I'm having an issue when my `Sass` compiles my `.scss` file. It seems that `Sass` compiles the `«` special characters and transform it in another one `┬½`. But I want to keep my `«` in my `.css` file.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Or maybe who knows how to ask `Sass` not to compile specific lines?

Here's my `scss` code:

```
/* SCSS file sample */
&::before{
    content: "«";
}

&::after{
    content: "»";
}
```

And here's how it compiles it:

```
/* Compiled CSS */
.textBox--quotation::before {
  content: "┬½";
}
.textBox--quotation::after {
  content: "┬╗";
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What compiler do you use? I guess that's a specific problem of your compiler. [This one](https://jsfiddle.net/2u43fhuo/) works. As well as [this](https://www.sassmeister.com).

Comment: I am using Sass 3.5.1 (Bleeding Edge)

Comment: Very strange behaviour. Because I did the same thing many times before with the same characters using `gulp-sass` and `compass.app` and all worked perfectly. Perhaps, you use non-`UTF8` character encoding?

Comment: Ye kinda strange. Unfortunately all my files are encoded in UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CSS equivalent of your special character:

`\00AB`
(As converted [here](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/))

```css
div:after {
  content: "\00AB";
}
```

```html
<div>hello  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this under Windows Sass 3.5.1 (Bleeding Edge).

When the file is encoded as UTF-8 [*with BOM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) this does not happen. Only when the file is encoded *without BOM* (which basically means, you encode UTF-8, but you are not telling anyone). My guess: Sass will parse the file as plain ANSI and thus sees these 2 characters.

<strike>**Funny thing**: When the file was encoded with BOM, sass removes it and adds an annotation `@charset "UTF-8";`</strike> Never mind, it always does this

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same charset problem.

Especially on OSX there seams to be a problem with ruby Encoding Settings.

I fixed it creating a config.rb file in the main project directory to tell ruby explicitly which charset encoding it should use. Since sass and compass depend on ruby, chances good that this might fix your problems.

```
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
```